# Mongo $lookup, which way is the fastest?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

it has been a while since I began using MongoDB aggregation.

It's a great way to perform complex queries and it has improved my app's performance in ways I never thought it was possible.

However, I came across `$lookup` and it appears that there are 3 ways of performing them. I would like to know what are the the advantages and drawbacks to each of them.
For the below examples, I am starting from `collectionA` using `fieldA` to match documents from `collectionB` using `fieldB`

1. What I'd call **preset $lookup**

```
{
   $lookup: {
       from: 'collectionB',
       localField: 'fieldA',
       foreignField: 'fieldB',
       as: 'documentsB'
   }
}
```

2. What I'd call **custom $lookup**

```
{
   $lookup: {
       from: 'collectionB',
       let: { valueA: '$fieldA' },
       pipeline: [
           {
               $match: {
                   $expr: {
                       $eq: ['$$valueA', '$fieldB']
                   }
               }
           }
       ],
       as: 'documentsB'
     }
}
```

3. Perfoming a **find** then an **aggregate** on `collectionB`

```
const docsA = db.collection('collectionA').find({}).toArray();
// Basically I will extract all values possible for the query to docB
const valuesForB = docsA.map((docA) => docA.fieldA);

db.collection('collectionB').aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            fieldB: { $in: valuesForB }
        }
    }
]);
```

I'd like to know which one is the fastest
If there are any parameters that makes one faster than the others
If there are any limitations to one of them

From what I can tell, I found :
**find + aggregate** faster than **preset $lookup** which is faster than **custom $lookup**
But then I wonder why **custom $lookup** exists...

Comment: *why custom $lookup exists* you can see pipeline property in custom lookup, it allows to do your custom operations in that collection's documents, for example if you want to lookup when 2 fields should be match with collection and you can't do with present lookup, you have to use custom lookup.

Comment: I forgot this usecase where 2 fields are required for matching `documentsB`. Even though I used it myself. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If data is too large than the preset lookup will be faster.
**why**

- All the data is looked up at the database level the data is to be held in another variable.
- While in find and aggregate will take longer as data is larger and while aggregating you are just increasing the data.

**TIP**
If you want to use **find and aggregate** than you should see the [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) query of MongoDB.
Example

```
var arr = db.collection('collectionA').distinct('fieldA',{});    
db.collection('collectionB').aggregate([
     { 
        $match: {
            fieldB: { $in: arr}
        }
    }
   ]);
```

Comment: I got it for the distinct, I wanted to write it in my question but then told myself that it's just for the likes of the question so I kept it with find. I could also do a projection within the find but that wasn't in my opinion the core of the question.

There's something interesting that you didn't write though. You explained why it would be faster with the preset $lookup. 

Do you know the differences between the **preset $lookup** and the **custom $lookup** inside the hood ?

Comment: @SeddikiAnass the performance of both lookup approach will be same, when you match with single field with $eq, the difference are: 1) you can use multiple conditions in pipeline lookup, 2) when you use other operators except $eq then it will not use index on field.

Answer (score 0):

"$expr", it doesn't use the indexes.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/